# Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Object .thumbnail has no method 'hover'

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ('.thumbnail').hover(
            function () {
            $('.hovImage').css('display', 'block');
        }, function () {
            $('.hovImage').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Object .thumbnail has no method 'hover'" with the above. I can't figure out where the error is coming from. Help please!

Comment: Can you post relevant html part? Hard to tell without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, got your problem, it's a syntax error, you're missing `$`:

```
||
VV
$('.thumbnail').hover()
```

Btw, you can just do this:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(
    function () {
    $('.hovImage').show();
}, function () {
    $('.hovImage').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one `$` here: `('.thumbnail').hover(`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.thumbnail').hover(
            function () {
            $('.hovImage').css('display', 'block');
        }, function () {
            $('.hovImage').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```